# Command to check the user access for all the queues

Tags: ibm-mq

Can someone please help me with a command to find the list of queues a particular user\group has in MQ?

Answer (score 1):

The dspmqaut command is used to display authorizations but you can't display a user group and find all the queues that way. 
Try using the dmpmqaut command which will dump all authorities to a file and you can then see the queues and which groups have access.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/fa15670_.htm

Using dmpmqaut with the -g GroupName parameter should give you the information you need.  For example:  dmpmqaut -m QMGRNAME -g groupname

Comment: Thank you Valerie for the detailed explanation. I'm going to try this.